# How to access a Web App deployed with access permissions set to only with company account?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, urlfetch

I'm trying to enable app scripts to be triggered by URL.

For this purpose I deploy the script as a Web App and then provide a button on the sheet that connects to a simple function that accesses the hardcoded URL.

My problem is that this mechanism only works if the Web App is deployed for `Anyone, even anonymous`. I'd rather keep it in the company domain, aka signed-in users.

However, `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)` does not work then even for signed-in users.

What can I do to enable only signed-in users to "run" the URL?

Comment: All the users have edit access to the sheet. It does not help

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script#samplescriptofclientside). You need to send access token in the header. If that doesn't work, provide [mre]:client side and server side.

Comment: Now I get this:
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Unauthorized</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>

Comment: Just created a simple script that prints the timestamp in the sheet. I cannot share a sheet due to company's policies

Comment: You don't have to share a sheet. Read [mre].[Edit] to provide both client side and server side scripts. If we load your code in our sheets, your error should be reproducible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem so this is what I did.

1. Created a custom function that checks for authorised users
2. Deployed the script such that it is accessible for `Anyone, even anonymous`

First, declare the domains you intend to allow access to -

```
var authorizedDomains = 'google.com,google.io,google.org'; // comma separated
// DO NOT add http or https
// Currently, this setup doesn't support sub-domains (as the regex has not been configured to handle that
```

Then use the following function that returns a **boolean** value (*true* or *false*) -

```
function userAccess() {
  var authorisedUser = false;
  var emailRegex = /\@(.*)/;
  var userDomain;
  try {
    userDomain = emailRegex.exec(activeUser)[1];
  } catch (error) {
  }
  var authorizedDomainNames = authorizedDomains.split(',');
  for (var i = 0; i < authorizedDomainNames.length; i++) {
    if (authorizedDomainNames[i] == userDomain) {
      authorisedUser = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  Logger.log(authorisedUser);
  return authorisedUser;
}
```

Finally, in your `doGet(e)` function, before serving the HTML file, wrap it with an `IF` condition; something as below -

```
function doGet(e) {
  var htmlFile;
  var title;
  if (userAccess()) {
    htmlFile = 'Index';
    title = 'Index'
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(htmlFile).setTitle(title);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sourabh. I try to run this solution and do not succeed with ```userDomain = emailRegex.exec(activeUser)[1];```. It remains underfined. What can be done?